# How to search inside a object using a index and search through the values of a array inside a object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have recently found a code that lets you get you the value of a array inside a object using a index number but i would like to search through that array of numbers how can i solve this problem?

this is the code that i have found using a index to get the array, i have tried using another function from a stackoverflow user but nothing seems to work.

```
let testObj = {
    tableA : [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1],
    tableB : [0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1],
    tableC : [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1],
    key : function(n){
        return this[Object.keys(this)[n]]
    }
}


    console.log(testObj.key(1));// [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1]
```

But i cant search through the tableA values with a for loop or for example i want to get the second number of that array like this

```
let testObj = {
    tableA : [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1],
    tableB : [0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1],
    tableC : [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1],
    key : function(n){
        return this[Object.keys(this)[n]]
    }
}


    console.log(testObj.key(1,0)); // 0
```

this code above is what i want to happen too use another index to get the value of that array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let testObj = {
    tableA : [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1],
    tableB : [0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1],
    tableC : [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1],
    key : function(n){
        return this[Object.keys(this)[n]]
    },
    nestedKey: function(n, x){
        return this[Object.keys(this)[n]][x]
    }
}
```

Is this what you wanted?

Update:

You can use your already defined `key` function aswell:

```
nestedKey: function(n, x){
        return this.key(n)[x]
}
```

Comment: You should add some commentary to explain what you've changed to give context to your answer.

Comment: exactly what i wanted idk how that slipped through my mind thank you!